# Dynamic Casting With Unknowns

Tags: c++, casting

New to C++ but still getting to grips with it. Using a template I have this:

```
template<typename TransportType>
Automobile<TransportType>::Automobile(std::string make)
    : Transport(make)
```

So I have a few of these which all inherit from "transport". For example another is:

```
template<typename TransportType>
Aircraft<TransportType>::Aircraft(std::string make)
    : Transport(make)

Automobile<Coach> * coach = new Automobile<Coach>("Volvo");
Aircraft<JumboJet> * jumbojet = new Aircraft<Jumbojet>("Boeing");`
```

My question is, if I have one transport type how can I "convert" it to another **WITHOUT** putting the transport type in until run time. EG:

```
*coach = dynamic_cast<*jumbojet typeid<transporttype>>(jumbojet);`
```

(The bit where I'm not sure being *jumbojet typeid)

I had a look at memcpy but couldn't seem to make it work. (I understand there could be problems if the actual objects have pointers within them, which they don't.)

`memcpy(*jumbojet, *coach, sizeof(coach))`

Comment: You can't use `memcpy()` on class types. It won't work correctly. You can only use it on POD types.

Comment: So you want to cast an `Aircraft` to an `Automobile`? That seems like a design problem.

Comment: Its an example of what I'm trying to do (different names), but the code I have at the moment would be completely out of context without putting the whole project here. Basically, both derived classes have exactly the same functions (for simplicity they could be "getSpeed(), getWeight()" but I need to cast between them at runtime on a random basis. Not sure if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop trying to do that.  You don't need to cast at runtime.  Instead, consider using virtual functions (i.e. runtime polymorphism) to eliminate the need to cast base classes to arbitrary derived classes at runtime.

Comment: But is it possible? And also is it possible to create an exact replica of the object?

Comment: No, you cannot create a replica with memcpy.  But you can declare a `virtual Transport* clone() const = 0` method in the base class which is then overridden in each derived class to return a copy of that derived type.  This is somewhat common when you need to create "exact replicas" without knowing their type (n.b. you won't have more type information after the clone, since it returns a pointer to base by necessity).